# Are legal questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

At some other SE sites, legal and business questions are explicitly off-topic. I just checked the help center and I didn't see anything about that.

Are questions about copyrights, for example, on-topic here?

Comment: Depending on your question, you may be better served at Law.SE.

Answer (score 10):

As you can see from the [`copyright`](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright?mixed=1) tag, there are a number of questions about that subject.

It is important to note that **you should not seek, and should not trust, legal advice here** - this is a community of Movie and TV enthusiasts, not a legal team. If the question is particularly technical from a law standpoint its probably not the best place to ask it.

However if the question is broadly applicable to Movies and TV then its likely to be on-topic, especially if its on broad legal principles in Movie and TV production rather than something that is very specific to a particular territory.

Comment: It might also be worth noting - though that's not necessarily specific to legal questions rather than a general scope consideration of the site - that questions asking for *personal* advice on *your very own* film project (or whatever you intend to do with a copyrighted work) are likely off-topic, too. Questions should usually pertain to existing works or general film industry practice.

Comment: "You should not seek, and should not trust, legal advice here". Nor at Law.SE. Nor pretty much anywhere on the internet. An in-person lawyer is always better than strangers on the internet.